# Distributed Revision Control, Wiki, and Bug-Tracking all in one

Tags: repository, wiki, bug-tracking, fossil

I know about [Fossil](http://www.fossil-scm.org) but are there any alternatives? Something small and easy to install/configure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know there are quite a few git-based wikis such as [git-wiki](http://github.com/al3x/git-wiki/tree/master), [WiGit](http://el-tramo.be/software/wigit) and [gitit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/gitit-0.5.3).  A simple [google search](http://www.google.com.au/search?hl=en&q=git-based+wiki) will bring up many others, I'm sure.

I also know of some git-based bug trackers such as [ticgit](http://wiki.github.com/schacon/ticgit) which basically lets you keep your tickets in a separate branch of a git repository.  There's also [DisTract](http://www.distract.wellquite.org/).

But I'm not aware of anything else aside from Fossil that really tries to do what it does in one combined tool.

I'm curious what your experiences with Fossil have been. It's one of those things I find interesting but not been in a position to actually use as yet.

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. I have the same problem, very interested in Fossil for couple of months now but never used it on some real project, just played with it. 

I guess I will have to give it a try and then decide what and how to go further. Right now I'm Trac user but fossil does sound more flexible with "offline" mode and option to have it portable on my USB drive.