# Best solution for integrated bug tracking, wiki and version control

Tags: project-management, wiki, version-control, bug-tracking

I love the Google Project Hosting web app. It includes bug tracking, wiki and SCM in one interface. (Example: [WMD Editor](http://code.google.com/p/n2markdowneditors/))

This solution is closed source and not for sale. While searching similar solutions I found [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) which has a rougher interface.

Could you list similar solutions?

[Someone asked the same question, but specified Git as the SCM.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1170831/distributed-revision-control-wiki-and-bug-tracking-all-in-one)

Comment: Note that Google project hosting is only for Open Source projects

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might look at [redmine.org](http://redmine.org), I'm just getting familiar with it, having only used it on a project for a couple months, but liking it so far.

Comment: It looks nicer than Trac, and has native multiple project support.

Comment: I have been using redmine for a while, and it works great.

Answer (score 13):

[EDIT] Since I wrote this answer, an exciting new fully-integrated distributed project management software has hit 1.0: [Veracity](http://Veracity-SCM.Com/) by SourceGear.

---

[Fossil-SCM](http://Fossil-SCM.Org/) is a nice distributed SCM, where "SCM" has the *original* meaning of "Software Configuration Management" and not the new diluted meaning of "Source Code Management".

What this means is that Fossil integrates distributed version control, distributed bug tracking and distributed wiki into one repository. Not one *UI*, like, say, Trac but one *single repository*.

So, if you clone a Fossil repository, you do not just get the latest version of the source code plus all its history, like you would get with Git, Mercurial, Bazaar, Monotone, Darcs or any other version control system, you *also* get the current bug database plus all its history and the current wiki plus all its history.

Fossil is written by D. Richard Hipp, who is not only the author of SQLite but also CVSTrac (the precursor of Trac). So, you *know* it's gotta be good.

If you want to see an example of Fossil in action, just the follow the link I posted: Fossil is hosted in Fossil itself and the Fossil homepage is actually just the Fossil repository itself.

BTW: even if you don't end up using Fossil, just spend some time learning its concepts. It's a rather brilliant design, and you're probably going to learn something which you can apply even if you are using Trac, Git, Instiki or whatever.

Comment: Where is the view interface for Fossil? How can we get the website interface like the one on http://fossil-scm.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki for our own projects?

Answer (score 5):

If you're willing to tolerate closed source FogBugz is pretty good. http://www.fogcreek.com/FogBUGZ/

They'll let you test it for up to 2 people and if you decide you like it you can either licence space on their servers or purchase to run on your servers.

If you're an open source only kind of guy, I recommend diversifying.  Get a couple different pieces of software to do the different things you want.  Often times things like SVN will have post commit scripts to link your commits to your wiki or bug tracking, etc.

Its nice when things are bundled, but nicer when you can pick and choose the things you want.

Comment: Actually now, I believe they let you test it for as many people as you want for 45 days. Though I do remember it being two at some point in the not so distant past.

Comment: +1: we use it here at Inntec. The wiki had some irritating little problems, at least in the previous version, but for the most part we're all very happy.

Comment: Actually I was thinking in mixing MediaWiki with Bugzilla and Subversion

Comment: We actually used MediaWiki with Mantis and Subversion.  It worked out well for a while (I had some very impressive post commit scripts which I inherited), but ultimately FogBugz is just a cleaner interface

Answer (score 4):

[Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/) does all of these things.

Comment: I can't tell you exactly what I dislike about Trac, but I will continue to use it just until I learn to use a better solution.

Comment: If you can't tell me what you don't like about Trac, then it'll be hard to recommend something that solves your problem. You might also try LiquidPlanner or FogBugz, though I've never used those so I can't recommend them.

Answer (score 4):

If you really like the Google Hosting App, you might find [InDefero](http://indefero.net/) the right choice for you.

Answer (score 3):

I like [Assembla](http://www.assembla.com).

Answer (score 1):

FogBugz is pretty slick.  I've been using for a month and really like it.  It has a SCM plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need all three solutions (SCM, bug tracking, and wiki) in one solution?  Why not mix and match the solutions that work best for you?

I've never used Trac, but bugzilla works really well as a free bug tracker. There are lots of open source wikis out there, and for free SCMs, mercurial, git and subversion are all excellent choices.

For paid solutions, Atlassian Jira and Confluence (task tracking and wiki) are okay, but FogBugz is better. Perforce is IMHO the best non-free SCM out there.

Answer (score 0):

Did someone mention [Indefero?](http://www.indefero.net/tour/) Looks nice enough so non-techs wont be scared to use it, open source version, private projects... Git support, issue tracker... seems like a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'll have to go with echoesofspring on this one. Redmine looks to be a great system as issue tracking/ project management tool if you want to: 
     1. manage multiple projects with sub-projects 
     2. project/ task status transparency with clients or project managers
     3. repository integration (I haven't used it)
     4. Gant charts and calendars and more...

I chose it from this [wiki list of project management tools] :[1]http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_project_management_software#!